# How can I remove certain word from filename?

Tags: ssh, command-line, rename

I have files in the following directory: import/images

```
Documents\ProductImages\1.jpg
Documents\ProductImages\2.jpg
Documents\ProductImages\3.jpg
```

how can remove `Documents\ProductImages\` from filenames?

Comment: Are the ``\`` part of the file name or are you trying to show directory structure?  If the latter, are they **really** going that way ``\`` or `/`?

Comment: Yes it's a part of filename.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
for i in 'Documents\ProductImages\'*.jpg; do mv -n -- "$i" "${i##*\\}"; done
```

The `${i##*\\}` expansion removes the longest prefix that matches the pattern, here: everything up to the last backslash, which needs to be escaped with another one.

Comment: I always recommend `mv -i` or `mv -n` for bulk/automated moves, to avoid data loss in case of a naming conflict. Also, how about `for i in *\\*.jpg`, to avoid trying to rename files that already don't have backslashes?

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is usually the correct tool for this sort of thing, if It’s available on your system.

There are two possible versions I know of. They have a different syntax but both could be made to work for your example.

The version usually deployed on Red Hat family goes like this

```
rename 'Documents\ProductImages\' '' *.jpg
```

The other version could do it like this

```
rename 's/.*\\//' *.jpg
```

This assumes you just want to keep the part after the last `\`.  If you wanted to be more specific:

```
rename 's/^Documents\\ProductImages\\//' *.jpg
```